# What is the difference between BingMapsTask and MapsTask?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

```
BingMapsTask bingMapsTask = new BingMapsTask();
bingMapsTask.SearchTerm = "coffee";
bingMapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;
bingMapsTask.Show();

MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
mapsTask.SearchTerm = "coffee";
mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;
mapsTask.Show();
```

I am unable to find any difference between these two code blocks in terms of functionality. Am i missing something, there should be a reason for this.

Comment: By my knowledge, it's just a name change in the SDK from wp7 to wp8. And bingmapstask is kept for backwards compatibility...

Answer (score 0):

MapsTask opens up the app that is selected by the user as the phone's default voice navigation app whereas BingMapsTask opens up Bing maps only.

So if a user has selected Here Drive+ app as the default voice navigation app in settings, MapsTask should open Here Drive+ and BingMapsTask should open Bing Maps.

Comment: I tested it with a demo app and that doesn't seem to work the way you say. I have Here Drive+ selected as my default voice nav. app but these both tasks are still launching the (same) Maps app on my wp 8.1 preview version phone.